# How to select office notebooks in a data-driven way?

Tags: laptop, reliability

We are going to buy 20 new laptops for new employees (typical office tasks: Windows 10, web browser, MS Teams, MS Office, paint.net, with a 14 inch screen, for normal office or home-office working conditions). We don't have any special requirements to the hardware, so I've figured I would try to optimize it by reliability.

Specifically, I am looking for a laptop brand and model that would give the highest life expectation before failure, for the bucks.

What would be your advice? Is there any way to make this decision in a data-driven way, i.e. do you know any trustworthy web sites collecting hardware reliability statistics?

Answer (score 0):

If you live in a place where they ship to, the Framework laptop is really good. Almost everything is replacable, so if your screen dies, new screen instead of new laptop. (same with battery, keyboard, trackpad, storage, ram, motherboard and charger). It even allows you to save some money by installing Linux or putting it together yourself (or both). It is about as high end as a Macbook though, with similar price tag, although it fits all your requirements.